# Upgrading Excel 2010 add-in to office 2016

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon, ribbonx

When upgrading to Office 365 / Excel 2016, I found that it was extremely slow to open, and even slower to close:  Waiting 20-30 seconds to open to a blank workbook, and taking over a minute to close-down excel.

My investigations showed that the problem was an Office 2010 add-in.  The add-in is a custom one that I wrote a few years ago - it was created with the help of the CustomUIEditor tool (to allow me to create a Ribbon for my add-in) - i.e. it is a .XLAM add-in, not a COM one.

After lots of googling, I can't find much about add-in compatibility between Office 2010 and Office 365.  The CustomUIEditor that I used previously has not been updated in around 10 years, and I can't find a useful alternative.

Has anyone come across a similar issue before (and solved it?)  Do I need to recreate the add-in as a COM add-in?

Comment: What does the Add-in do?

Comment: Nothing special - creates a new ribbon item, some groups and some controls.  It is used for engineering conversion factors and calculations.  It does store some information in the "sheets" (hidden) that come with the .XLAM, and also adds a menu item to the worksheet context menu.

Comment: Honestly, this question is too broad. There can be many reasons and may need lot of time to analyse why it is happening

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that it is broad, but thank-you anyway for taking the time to respond.  I was essentially wondering if this is a general issue in that Office 2003 / 2010 RibbonX add-ins are not compatible with Office 2016, and I needed to migrate it to COM or similar. I guess it's not that simple.

Comment: There is no such compatible issue. My add-ins created in 2010 work just fine in Office 2016 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - thanks to Siddharth for taking the time to respond.  I managed to solve my Excel issue, and in the end it was unrelated to the add-in (even though disabling the add-in did improve the speed that Excel opened and closed).

The issue was related to a lot of old files in my %appdata%\roaming\microsoft\excel\ folder.  Lots of corrupted files that it was trying to read / write back when I opened or closed excel.  I deleted them and Excel is now working properly.